# Unable to connect to geth

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket

I'm totally new to Ethereum, and want to create some deposit address monitoring system using web socket. Which gets newly generated blocks and scan it for transactions made into it.
You can find code here:
https://github.com/AlanL1/Ethereum-FrontEnd

But geth is not connected with application. I have already installed `geth`

[image]

Am i missing something?

Comment: Is metamask installed, if yes, you can select metamask network "localhost 8545" from metamask dropdown. metamask itself injects web3 instance, you should create new instance like 'web3js' with window.web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

Comment: If I select local host from dropdown, it just stuck with _Connecting to Unknown Private Network_

Comment: start geth with "geth --testnet --rpc --rpccorsdomain="*"

Comment: `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

Comment: you must have already running geth

Comment: Okay, closed the another instance, now geth is running, code modified as you suggested, but still it's not able to connect :(

Comment: have you selected localhost option in MetaMask

Comment: Yes: https://imgr.es/4B2P

Comment: ok. in your transaction.html you are using websockets, whereas on port 8545 http-rpc server is running, you need to expose websocket interface , but even after exposing websocket interface, it will not work.  Metamask uses web3.js version 0.20.x, which does not support websocket provider.

Comment: you have to use web3.js version 1.0.0 which is still in beta, to use websockets, simultaneously you will have to disable metamask also.

Comment: In every page you do not have to initialize web3. Once it is done, it can be accessed on other pages also.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not knowing how to make it work :( could you please modify your answer

Comment: Changing my answer won’t help... you need to use web3.js  version 1.0.0 , expose websocket interface on geth , initialise web3 once on first page only and disable metamask

Comment: Okay, which version is this?: https://github.com/AlanL1/Ethereum-FrontEnd/blob/master/web3.min.js

Comment: Version : 0.20.1

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! do you have any link of documentation for it?

Comment: Will write a document and share.. but it will take one day..

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated! Please let me update the link once you done it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this sample code:

```
    if(type of web3 !== 'undefined'){
         // Use injected web3 by Metamask/Mist
         window.web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
     } else {
         // Fallback to local node
         // you can use Infura Node Urls also
         // 'http://127.0.0.1:8545' will be replaced by 
         // 'https://ropsten.infura.io/<API KEy>'
         window.web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
     }
```

here you can see i have added **web3js** instance, instead of replacing **web3** instance injected by Metamask or Mist.

**Update**

To consume JSON-RPC API's over WebSockets, use web3.js beta version 1.0.0-beta https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/1.0

First expose RPC API's over Web Socket Interface

```
geth --testnet --ws --wsorigins="*"
```

then instantiate web3 in your page as

```
web3 = new Web3("ws://127.0.0.1:8546");
```

Written a detailed blog on setting up local geth node & communicating with it. http://blog.kherwa.com/2018/05/10/building-a-dapp-series-part1-set-up-and-communicate-with-an-ethereum-node/